# Flex 4 PrintDataGrid validNextPage doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, printing, reporting, flex-spark

I'm trying to create a report viewer for flex.
The reports will be built from a PrintDataGrid since it's the only component in flex that supports multi-pages through validNextPage and nextPage().

Basically, I'm trying to populate a collection of the report pages through the following code:

```
var index:int = 0;
dataProvider = new ArrayCollection();
do {
    var rep:Report = new Report();
    rep.height = 841;
    rep.width = 595;
    rep.pageNumber = index + 1;

    var i:int = index;
    while (i > 0) {
        rep.nextPage();
        i--;
    }

    dataProvider.addItem(rep);
    index++;
} while (rep.validNextPage);
```

My problem is that I get stuck in an endless loop since validNextPage returns true all the time.
Am I trying to do something impossible? I saw some examples of adding a report page to FlexPrintJob but I've never seen an example of adding a report page to a component on the screen.

Another issue that I have is that this report should be dynamic (sortable) but I can't add the same report to 2 parents, hence I create a new Report on every iteration (but that will become problematic as I try to sort the report since i'll have several instances of this report)

Anyone has any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

could you provide more code. What is the Report object for example?

You can also check Adobe's website about Printing Multipage Output [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=printing_5.html).